# Automating SFTP using LFTP

Tags: lftp

I have a weekly file transfer to one of our vendors that I am trying to automate.
They require that we transfer the file using sftp.  We login to their SFTP server using a userid and password.

My script works connecting to their server but then does not process any further commands.
My question is can I pass LFTP a script to execute once logged in?

Here is my script.  With the credentials changed to protect the innocent.

```bsh
fromfile=$1
cd /ssg/cc/outgoing
echo "sftping file ..."
echo $fromfile
lftp -u prodlogin,prodpassword sftp://sftp.datacloud.server.com
cd inbox
!ls
put $fromfile
dir
bye
mv $fromfile /ssg/cc/save/$fromfile
```

I feel like there is something simple I am missing here.  That is why I was wondering if I could pass the commands to `lftp` via a script file.

Comment: Thank you.  I have seen those, but I am unsure how to combine them with the -u I am using to connect to their sftp server.

Comment: I believe I have found the solution.  Instead of using the -u to connect, I am using the -c then using the open statement to connect to the sftp server.  Then adding the rest of the commands separated by semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

You almost don't need a script

```
#!/bin/bash
fromfile="$1"
echo "SFTPing file: $fromfile"

lftp --user 'prodlogin' --password 'prodpassword' sftp://sftp.datacloud.server.com/~/inbox -e "put /ssg/cc/outgoing/$fromfile; exit" &&
    mv -f "/ssg/cc/outgoing/$fromfile" /ssg/cc/save/
```

Comment: I just noticed this comment.  I will give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Looks much better than using the -c route.

Comment: If this answer is best for you please remember to accept it; that's how you say "thanks" here